# VBA - replace characters in string

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have 1 column, which should contain an amount, but it has incorrect formatting and it is treated as text.

[image]

Therefore, there is necessary to replace dot for nothing and then comma for dot. I have code:

```
Private Sub Correction_of_dot()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    i = "."
    k = ""
    Columns("P:P").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub

Private Sub Correction_of_comma()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    i = ","
    k = "."
    Columns("P:P").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

But it does nothing... no errors, just loading and then nothing has happened. Could you advise me, what I've did wrong or what can I do better, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: When and How are those Subs been called? Isn't it easier just changing the column datatype to the format needed?

Comment: The code appears correct however it may be worth explicitly declaring the worksheet e.g Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("P")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my regional settings, Dot is used as a decimal separator and Comma is used as a thousand separator. Having said that, the following code works for me and produce the expected output.

To test the code, I copied the numbers from the web page and pasted on the sheet, they look like below...

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub Test()
With Range("P:P")
    .Replace ".", ""
    .Replace ",", "."
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could loop through the column and use the Replace function.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim finalRow As Long

finalRow = SheetX.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to finalRow

   SheetX.Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(SheetX.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".", "")
   SheetX.Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(SheetX.Cells(i, 1).Value, ",", ".")

Next i
```

Note: I didn't test this - but it should work.
Also: Change SheetX to whatever sheet CodeName is appropriate and change the column reference as needed (column 1 in this example)

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution that does not require Macro intervention is to select column with text values, goto `Data` Tab==>`Text to Columns`==>Next==>Next==>select `General` Column data format.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can also tell Excel if comma is a decimal or thousand separator (under advanced options)...

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in this case due to the mix of decimal separators

Comment: Actually it works, in case it doesn't recognize automatically, you can always use advanced Text settings...

Comment: Didn't work in my test but didn't try to use the `Advanced Text Import Settings` which I see you've now added

Comment: for large datasets, this is clearly the most efficient solution, including from VBA

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. The code first changes your language to match what the decimal separators are in your column. Which then makes Excel recognise it as a number stored as text. It then uses `text to columns` to convert the range to numbers before resetting the decimal (and thousands) separators back to what they should be - leaving your data now stored as numbers

```
Sub CorrectIncorrectNumberFormat()
    With Application
        .UseSystemSeparators = False
        .DecimalSeparator = ","
        .ThousandsSeparator = "."
    End With

    'Update to your applicable range I've set it to sheet1 Column A
    With Sheet1
        With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End With
    End With

    With Application
        .DecimalSeparator = "."
        .ThousandsSeparator = ","
        .UseSystemSeparators = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print generateNumber("1.525,32")
    'works with mixed formats:
    Debug.Print generateNumber("12,525.33")
    Debug.Print generateNumber("1,112.525,35")

End Sub

Public Function generateNumber(strInput As String) As Double

    strInput = Replace(Replace(strInput, ".", ""), ",", "")

    generateNumber = CDbl(Left(strInput, Len(strInput) - 2))

    'getting the first digit after the comma
    generateNumber = generateNumber + 0.1 * CLng(Mid(strInput, Len(strInput) - 1, 1))

    'getting the second digit after the comma
    generateNumber = generateNumber + 0.01 * CLng(Mid(strInput, Len(strInput), 1))

End Function
```

If the input is standard, with 2 digits after the whole number, it would return a standard output.

It has a small plus over formatting, because in different countries the separators are different.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for me; if it doesn't work in your case I think the column is formatted as text; just change the formatting to numbers or Standard.

try this:

```
Private Sub Correction_of_dot()
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    i = "."
    k = ""
    Columns("P:P").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

    i = ","
    k = "."
    Columns("P:P").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```